# Where to place a question about Google Maps algorithm for arranging tiles and its artifacts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

This question doesn't seem to be very welcome in stackoverflow despite there exist the tags google-maps and satellite-image, so I am guessing where should I place it:
[Weird regions in lagoon water ripples pattern (Google Maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827579/weird-regions-in-lagoon-water-ripples-pattern-google-maps)

Is gis.SE a better place, regarding the answer could be related to an algorithm artifact, a mathematical surface mapping issue, less probably a physical phenomenon...?

Comment: In its current form I doubt it fits on any site. It is far too broad of a question.

Answer (score 4):

In general questions about Google Maps are on-topic at the [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com).

Your question looks like it is about Remote Sensing rather than GIS but the community there generally places it under the same umbrella.

However, I recommend revising your question to make clearer what the single question you wish to ask is before you post it there.

---

Since you posted [Weird regions in lagoon water ripples pattern (Google Maps)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374139) at GIS SE it has received two answers so far.